# Копирайт в шапке php файла для Notepad++

Tags: php, notepad++, авторские-права

Подскажите, есть ли плагины или решения, чтоб вставлять копирайт автора с временем сохранения файла в Notepad++?

Comment: неужели тут нет людей, которые пользуются Notepad++ и не думали о своей работе?

Comment: @wwwplaton, все эти люди пользуются IDE и темплейтами файлов. А время сохранения и так есть в виде метки mtime или коммита в репе.

Comment: к примеру ?

Comment: @wwwplaton к примеру что?

Comment: @wwwplaton, к примеру, в PHPStorm, можно сделать кастомный темплейт для класса, где копирайт и прочее будет генериться в php-doc. К тому же вы программист или нет? Автоматизируйте!

Answer (score 0):

Плагин TextFX + гарячие клавиши при каждом редактировании. Полной автоматизации к сожалению нет.